# Cannot open *.P65 file in InDesign Adobe

Tags: error-handling, adobe, adobe-indesign, bookshelf-pagemaker

I cannot open *.p65 file(s) in Adobe InDesign (version 17.2 x64) that's installed on Windows 10.
Any suggestions on how to open *.P65 File in InDesign, Any Plug-in Required?
Also, How to convert *.P65 File into a PDF file?

.P65 is an older version of Page Maker, which seems to be replaced by InDesign. Yesterday, I installed Indesign but sadly, I cannot open that file.

Kindly suggest. Thank you in advance.

[image: Adobe InDesign - P65 File Open Error]

Comment: Oh... I just tried and, yep, my latest version of InDesign (17.1 MacOS) can't open my old .p65 files, indeed.

Comment: But I still have InDesign CS6 on my old Win PC. It can open .p65 files.

Comment: I asked the same (original post) questions in the Adobe Community and I have received following answer, refer the link: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/cannot-open-p65-file-s-in-adobe-indesign-version-17-2-x64/m-p/12857156#M472146

Comment: It's likely I still have PageMaker on my another ancient PC. So probably I can open your file directly and export it in PDF. Let me know if you need help.